# Sometimes bot won't add role and set the nickname

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I set up a bot so whenever someone types *t!accept @user [nickname]* it will add a role to the user and changes the user's nickname. This is my code :

```
    mention = message.mentions.members.first();

        if (msg.startsWith (prefix + "accept")){
            if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.reply("You have no permission!");
            if (mention == null) { return; }
            let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2);
            mention.roles.add('123456789')
            mention.setNickname(mention.displayName+" "+args.join('  '))
            mention.send("Congratulations");

            try{
                await message.author.send("Sent.")
            }catch(e){
                message.channel.send("An error has occured.")
            }
        }
```

However, only most of the time it will fully work, sometimes it won't do both things, and sometimes it will only do one of the task (Add role, but not nickname and vice versa)

Is there anything wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the bot's role above the roles of the users you're using the command on?

Comment: Yes it has administrator permissions and basically above all roles.

Comment: Do you ever get errors when it does not work?

Comment: No, no errors, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the nickname you're providing at times is too long and exceeds discords nickname length limit of 32 characters. You should add a check of: 
`if ((mention.displayName + " " + args.join(" ")).length > 32) return message.channel.send("The nickname exceeds 32 characters")`
However that could not be it of course, I would've posted a comment beforehand but I unfortunately do not have enough reputation.

Comment: Hello, thanks. But whenever the nickname is longer than 32 characters it'll show up an error on the logs and I can identify it easily. However, this issue doesn't create any error logs.